# Why does ObjectOutputStream write symbols to a file instead of my input?

Tags: java, objectoutputstream

I am trying to write my `ArrayList`, named `Clients`, to a file. It works, but unfortunately it just writes symbols into the file and not my actual input.

Below is my code:

```
    public void SaveToFile() {

    try 
    {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("CustomerLists.txt");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(Clients);
        oos.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
   }
```

How do I make it work?

Comment: Do you understand what `writeObject` does?

Comment: It prints in binary format. It's not meant to be human readable.

Comment: Or perhaps more importantly, do you understand what [`ObjectOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) does? It creates a **binary** stream of serialized Java objects and values. It you want text, create a [`FileWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) instead of the `FileOutputStream`, and optionally wrap that in a [`PrintWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) and/or a [`BufferedWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write Serialized Object as Human readable Txt file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16817210/5221149)

Comment: The crux of this question is about what `ObjectOutputStream` is for; neither of those possible duplicates really address that.

Comment: @dimo414 The crux of this question is that the OP is expecting to create a text file, and both duplicates address that precisely.

Comment: @EJP well, the goal is to write a text file, but the *confusion* stems from misunderstanding the purpose of `ObjectOutputStream`. Anyways, OP has what they need now.

Comment: @dimo414 thank you for understanding the other question doesn't address what I am looking for at all,

Comment: @EJP I am dealing with ArrayList here, I know how to write to txt file but my struggle is writing an arraylist to text file

Comment: @Andreas I changed it the way you told me using Filewriter and BufferedReader but my problem here is you see where I wrote oos.writeobject(Clients) - Clients is my array and when I change it to oos.write it wont allow me because it is a arraylist so what would be an alternative for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've done is *serialize* a Java object to a file with `ObjectOutputStream`. That means, Java transforms your object `Clients` into a specific representation, which covers all the state your object has, e.g. member variables. This representation is not meant to be human-readable, it is a **binary format**, which is more efficient and suitable for classes and the Java enviroment, than a text format. Look [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/objectoutputstream_writeobject.htm) for more information.

What you can do instead is use a [`FileWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html), [`BufferedWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) or [`PrintWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html), which have multiple `write[...](...)` methods to write text to a file. In this case, you have to write each variable for its own as `String`, etc., not the whole class. [Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_filewriter_class.htm) you can an find example on that.

Another option to do the same as `ObjectOutputStream` for a whole object but in a completely customizable fashion and human-readable form is to use the [Java Architecture for XML Binding (JAXB)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Architecture_for_XML_Binding), but this requires a bit of reading. There are also other object serialization libraries for JSON and other formats.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is it when I run this java program it creates the text file but it prints out symbols instead of my input?

Because it isn't a text file. It is serialized data, written according to the Java Serialization Protocol, because you're using `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject()`.

That also means that `CustomerLists.txt` is not an appropriate name for this file.

If you want text, use `PrintWriter` or `BufferedWriter`.